# Javascript running twice instead of once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have made the demo below to simplify my big problem, when enter "first input", click submit, click returned"first input", it alert once.  However,refresh, when enter "first input",submit, then enter "second input",submit, click "first input", browser alert TWICE when intended to run once. What's the problem? How to fix this?

Html file (index.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="inputtext" type="text">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="returned_result"></div>


<script>
$("#submit").click(function(){

    var content=$("#inputtext").val(); //get the value of input field

    $.post("testclick2.php", {content:content}, function(result){
    $("#returned_result").prepend(result);
     });

    $("#inputtext").val(""); //clear the input area

})

</script>
```

testclick2.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
$content=$_POST["content"];
echo "<div class=\"content\">".$content."</div>"."<br>";
?>

<script>
$(".content").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
})
</script>
```

Comment: Is that all of your HTML?

Comment: YUP what's the matter?

Comment: @问题大王 What is the rendered output for the testclick2.php? Add another set of HTML, that gets to the browser when you access both the pages?

Comment: testclick1 is the front end, testclick2 is the backend.   You need to enter some random text in the input field to see the rendered output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove your listener before you add it:

```
$("#submit").off('click');
$("#submit").click(function(){...}
```

And

```
$(".content").off('click');
$(".content").click(function(){...}
```

Comment: Well, this is a hack, but the real problem is in the rendered HTML. By the way, this works too! `:)`

Comment: @Parvenu Kumar Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two alerts because you are returning twice the `click` handler with the `.post` response.

Basically with each additional submit you will get an additional alert.

Remove your `click` handler from the `POST` response and attach the event to the `body` so it can handle dynamically added elements.

add this into your main `<script>` section:

```
$('body').on('click', '.content', function() {
    alert("i've been clicked once");
});
```

and your `php` file will be only this:

```
<?php
    $content=$_POST["content"];
    echo '<div class="content">' . $content . '</div>' . '<br>';
?>
```

without the need to load `jquery` or outputting any `javascript`

Comment: Thanks for the life-changing tutorial.